# Why OpenCV Mat creates memory leaks?

Tags: node.js, opencv, mat

Not sure if this is relevant, but I'm using `opencv4nodejs` for my project, and I did run in this situation where if I don't call `.release()` on each Mat object, the memory consumption goes up ~10MB/s.

This simple example code will crate the issue.

```
function loop(camera, display)
{
    let mat = camera.read();

    let grey_mat = mat.bgrToGray();

    loop(camera, display);
}
```

Where as, this one fixes the problem:

```
function loop(camera, display)
{
    let mat = camera.read();

    let grey_mat = mat.bgrToGray();

    grey_mat.release();

    mat.release();

    loop(camera, display);
}
```

If I search for why OpenCV Mat object causes leaks I get answers where people say that Mat is capable of taking care of memory usage on its own.

If the last statement is true, what am I doing wrong? And if I'm not doing anything wrong, why do I have to explicitly tell a Mat object to release its memory? Or, is there a potential issue with the npm module `opencv4nodejs` itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your are using `recursion`. At the end of the function you call `loop` again so it stacks new instances of these `Mat` a every recursion. The objects mat and grey_mat are never destroyed, they would if you were to return from the function tough.

If you change the loop for something `iterative` you shouldn't encounter the issue anymore as the function returns everytime and the mats are destroyed.

```
function doLoopWork(camera, display)
{
    let mat = camera.read();

    let grey_mat = mat.bgrToGray();
}

function loop(camera, display) 
{
    while (1) {
      doLoopWork(camera, display);
   }
}
```